# How do I find if a root uri tree exist?

Tags: java, android, tree, uri

I get a tree uri from OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE, and want to know if folder exsist in case user deleted. I tried doc == null from treeUri and single, and also exists but they dont they both show not null when folder is deleted.
Thanks

Comment: Try to list the content of the tree.

Comment: Its for the main tree though, if by some chance the main folder gets deleted i want to recreate it.

Comment: We know. List the contents of the main tree was the idea. And suggested ;-)

Comment: `a tree uri from use folder,` I wonder what you mean with 'from use folder'. Never heard talking like that.

Comment: @blackapps I see the work around, but that only works if theres no contents anf folders not there  but user could delete contents and not folder. Ive decided to use getName() if it equals folder name. Sorry for my unpolitical correctness though it saves data space ww, i meant OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.

Answer (score 1):

Try to list the content of the tree.

If the tree does not exist anymore you will get an exception or a null cursor.

Comment: Im not to familiar with exceptions, how would i handle to find out if it doesnt exist, or where would null show. Could you show an exapmle please.

Comment: You could start with listing files and folders for that tree. Pretty basic stuff. You will automaticaly then see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Yea I remember now about exceptions, like i said on your first comment i will use getName(), less code and faster. Though i will use catch so ill like comment for you. Thanks a little code wouldnt hurt, i mean even if someone just copied and pasted all day the logic is still the main mathematics of it all. Just sayin

Comment: I have no idea what getName() has to do with this.

Comment: Well, it will show the name of my main folder for restoring if it exist with DocumentFile Doc7 = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(uri); String Godisgood = Doc7.getName();, or like u said throw exception. I liked your comment for the exception part but getName is quicker.

Comment: Quicker to what? Does it tell you if the tree still exists? Unclear.

Comment: Quicker =Less code/lessprocessing, well if the getName doesnt equal my folder name it doesnt exist cus the exception will throw like u said.

Comment: Great/ SImpler than listing.

Comment: DocumentFile.getName() will return null if the tree does not exist anymore. I can confirm.

Comment: Is that on main tree, though of uri that was taken flags? And did u just use fronTree for DocumentFile?

Comment: I dont understand all your questions. You asked `How do I find if a root uri tree exist?`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242388/discussion-between-j-m-and-blackapps).

Comment: You know what it works now with exists, i dont know what my mistake was. Thanks anyways i delete this question soon.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do something like that? with the **findFile()** method?

```
Uri treeUri = uri;
DocumentFile root = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, treeUri);
if (root.findFile("Foldername") == null) { //create folder }
```

Comment: Im trying to find out if the "treeUri" exist, and that would be the main root. Thanks though for your time